# Jest - How to test output of react methods is correct?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I am having problems trying to understand how I can use Jest to test the output of a method in a react file. I am completely new to this style of web development so any help is appreciated.

I have a js file like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import 'es6-promise';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';

export default class FetchData extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { documents: [], loading: true };
        fetch('api/SampleData/GetDocuments')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ documents: data, loading: false });
            });
    }

    render() {
        let contents = this.state.loading ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
            : FetchData.renderdocumentsTable(this.state.documents);

        return <div>
            <button onClick={() => { this.refreshData() }}>Refresh</button>
            <p>This component demonstrates bad document data from the server.</p>
            {contents}
        </div>;
    }

    refreshData() {
        fetch('api/SampleData/GetDocuments')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ documents: data, loading: false });
            });
    }

    static renderdocumentsTable(documents) {
        return <table className='table'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Filename</th>
                    <th>CurrentSite</th>
                    <th>CorrectSite</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {documents.map(document =>
                    <tr className="document-row" key={document.documentId}>
                        <td>{document.filename}</td>
                        <td>{document.currentSite}</td>
                        <td>{document.correctSite}</td>
                    </tr>
                )}
            </tbody>
        </table>;
    }
}
```

I basically want to be able to test that a table is returned with the correct number of columns however I can't work out exactly how to do this with Jest.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I follow next approach:

1. [Mocking dependencies](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules) called explicitly by component under test.
2. Initializing component with [`shallow()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html)
3. trying different modifications
4. Checking component with [`.toMatchSnapshot()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/snapshot-testing)

Under "trying different modifications" I mean either creating component with different initial `props` or interacting with component's internal elements' `props`.

```
test('closes list on button clicked', () => {
    let wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent prop1={'a'} prop2={'b'} />);
    wrapper.find('button').at(0).simulate('click');
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

This way you never need to test methods separately. Why do I believe this make sense?

While having all per-method tests passed we still cannot say if it works as a whole(false-positive reaction). 
Also if we do any refactoring like renaming method our tests-per-method will fail. At the same time component may still work perfectly fine and we spend more time to fix tests just to have them pass(false-negative reaction).

From the opposite focusing on `render()` outcomes(that's what Enzyme adapter does under the hood of `.toMatchSnapshot()` matcher) we test what our element does as a part of React project.

[UPD] Example based on your code:

```
describe("<FetchData />", () => {
  let wrapper;
  global.fetch = jest.fn();

  beforeEach(() => {
    fetch.mockClear();
  });

  function makeFetchReturning(documents) {
    fetch.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({ json: () => documents }));
  }

  function initComponent() {
    // if we run this in beforeEach we would not able to mock different return value for fetch() mock
    wrapper = shallow(<FetchData />); 
  }

  test("calls appropriate API endpoint", () => {
    makeFetchReturning([]);
    initComponent();
    expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith("api/SampleData/GetDocuments");
  });

  test("displays loading placeholder until data is fetched", () => {
    // promise that is never resolved
    fetch.mockImplementation(() => new Promise(() => {})); 
    initComponent();
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  test("looks well when empty data returned", () => {
    makeFetchReturning([]);
    initComponent();
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  test("reloads documents and displays them", () => {
    makeFetchReturning([]);
    initComponent();
    // no matter what values we include in mock but it should be something non-empty
    makeFetchReturning([{fileName: '_', currentSite: '1', correctSite: '2'}]);
    wrapper.find('button').at(0).simulate('click');
    expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  })

});
```

Comment: I am trying lots of the stuff like you said however am still not getting it right. None of the tutorials online seem to have example that look like my react class. E.g       
import React from 'react';
import FetchData from './fetchdata';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

it('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer
        .create(<FetchData></FetchData>)
        .toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
}); Just doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please give an example using the class I attached to my original question? :)

Comment: Amazing. Thank you very much!

Comment: Note: I also needed to add enzyme and set that up for shallow :)